# Fm Elfinder not giving correct path

Tags: php, symfony, elfinder

I'm using elfinder as filesystem on our webpage. We set our folderpaths in yml file and I got some problems after changing location from article_images to images/article_images.

When clicking on a input-field, the elFinder opens. Then I browse for a photo, dobble-clicks, and the input-field should be filled with the path.

[image]

This should actually be /images/articcle_images/.....

This is very weird, because the location in the yml must be right because:

- The elFinder opens right folder
- When rightclicking a picture and press Link, it opens the picture in a new tab with correct url (with /images)

After a lot of searching, I belive this must be a cinfiguration problem. This is my configuration:

```
article_form:
                locale: %locale% # defaults to current request locale
                editor: form # other choices are tinymce or simple, and form
                fullscreen: true # defaults true, applies to simple and ckeditor editors
                include_assets: true # disable if you want to handle loading of the javascript and css assets yourself
                connector:
                    debug: false # defaults to false
                    roots:       # at least one root must be defined
                        uploads:
                            driver: LocalFileSystem
                            path: %article_images%
                            upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
                            upload_deny: ['all']
                            upload_max_size: 2M
                            url: %article_images%
```

Is there something missing from my configuration?

Comment: hi Ruben, what value contain %article_images% variable, also how physically files located relatively to web root?